# Netsuite report list field

Tags: netsuite

I want to create a list field of saved reports in Netsuite Project record. 
I created a saved search for the report type. but I cannot load that search in user-event script. I want to load the search and give addSelectOption of that search to the scripted field. But i get this error: UNABLE_TO_DETERMINE_RECORD_TYPE_FOR_SAVED_SEARCH_ID_1

> var searchReport = search.load({
>                           id: 'customsearch461'
>                       }); //Reward Project Report Search

```
var searchRs = searchReport.run().getRange({start:0,end:1000});
              for (index in searchRs)
              {
                    var searchRecord = searchRs[index];
                    var InternalId = searchRecord.getValue(searchRecord.columns[0]);                   
                    addSelectOption(field,report);
              }
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the report search type is not supported by SuiteScript.